# Jar-program built by Ant doesn't see the class with the explicitly set classpath

Tags: java, ant, classpath

So, here's my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <project name="test" default="hello_jar">
  <path id="commons" >
    <fileset dir="lib">
      <include name="commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src/test_package" destdir="build/classes" classpathref="commons"/>
  </target>
<target name="hello_jar" depends="compile">
  <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
  <jar destfile="build/jar/hello.jar">
    <fileset dir="build/classes">
      <include name="test_package/Hello.class"/>
    </fileset>
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test_package.Hello"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
</target>
```

After successfully building a jar, I execute it with explicitly set classpath:

```
java -classpath lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar -jar build/jar/hello.jar test_package.Hello
```

and I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/math/Range
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.math.Range
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

Why can't it find the 'commons-lang' jar?

Comment: You can't specify both `-jar` and `-cp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should choose:

- either you use `-jar`, and the JVM will use the classpath specified in the manifest file inside the jar. It will also use the manifest to know which main class must be executed. There should thus be no `-cp` option, and no class name specified:

  ```
  java -jar build/jar/hello.jar
  ```
- or you use `-cp` (or `-classpath`), and you should add every jar in the classpath (commons and hello), and you should specify the main class name to execute:

  ```
  java -cp lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:build/jar/hello.jar test_package.Hello
  ```

In your case, since you haven't configured the classpath in the manifest, you should choose the second option.